# Disable draggable after dropped on droppable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a drag and drop project and have run into a little problem.
I want to disable the draggable after it has been dropped on the droppable. I have a function, `disableDrag`, but I get an error in the console and then it logs but doesn't do the function. 
Do anyone know why? And is there a better way to do this?

HTML setup:

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="key" class="fragment">
    <div class="key"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="dragonkey" class="fragment">
    <div class="key"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="inventory">
    <div class="slot" id="slot1"></div>
    <div class="slot" id="slot2"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS setup:

```
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
#key, #dragonkey{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute !important;
  z-index:999;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:DarkGoldenRod;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
#key{
  top:5%;
  left:5%;
}
#dragonkey{
  top:15%;
  left:5%;
}
#inventory{
  width:68px;
  height:68px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  margin:5% 5% 0 0;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.slot{
  border:2px solid #fff;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
}
#slot1, #slot2{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.ui-droppable-active{
  background-color:rgba(184,134,11,0.7) !important;
}
```

This is the jQuery setup:

```
// Javascript document

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#key").draggable({
    containment: ".container"
  });

  $("#dragonkey").draggable({
    containment: ".container"
  });

  $("#slot1").droppable({
    accept: "#key",
    drop: dropAnimate
  });

  $("#slot2").droppable({
    accept: "#dragonkey",
    drop: dropAnimate
  });

  function dropAnimate(event, ui) {

    console.log( $(ui.draggable).attr('id'));

    var $this = $(this);

    var width = $this.width();
    var height = $this.height();
    var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
    var cntrTop = (height / 2) - (ui.draggable.height() / 2);

    ui.draggable.position({
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: $this,
      using: function(pos) {
        $(this).animate(pos, "slow", "linear");
      }
    });
    disableDrag();
  }

  function disableDrag () {
    $(this).draggable({
      disabled: true
    });
    console.log("DISABLED");
  }


}); <!-- END OF DOCUMENT READY -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ui.draggable` element to set the `disabled: true` on:

```
ui.draggable.draggable({disabled: true});
```

Check this example:

```js
// Javascript document
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#key").draggable({
    containment: ".container"
  });

  $("#dragonkey").draggable({
    containment: ".container"
  });

  $("#slot1").droppable({
    accept: "#key",
    drop: dropAnimate
  });

  $("#slot2").droppable({
    accept: "#dragonkey",
    drop: dropAnimate
  });

  function dropAnimate(event, ui) {

    console.log( $(ui.draggable).attr('id'));

    var $this = $(this);

    var width = $this.width();
    var height = $this.height();
    var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
    var cntrTop = (height / 2) - (ui.draggable.height() / 2);

    ui.draggable.position({
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: $this,
      using: function(pos) {
        $(this).animate(pos, "slow", "linear");
      }
    });
    
    ui.draggable.draggable({disabled: true});
  }

}); <!-- END OF DOCUMENT READY -->
```

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
#key, #dragonkey{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute !important;
  z-index:999;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:DarkGoldenRod;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
#key{
  top:5%;
  left:5%;
}
#dragonkey{
  top:15%;
  left:5%;
}
#inventory{
  width:68px;
  height:68px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  margin:5% 5% 0 0;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.slot{
  border:2px solid #fff;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
}
#slot1, #slot2{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.ui-droppable-active{
  background-color:rgba(184,134,11,0.7) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="key" class="fragment">
    <div class="key"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="dragonkey" class="fragment">
    <div class="key"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="inventory">
    <div class="slot" id="slot1"></div>
    <div class="slot" id="slot2"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `disableDrag` function, `this` doesn't point to the element being dragged; it points to the Window object. Fix that by passing the draggable element to the function with `disableDrag($this);`. Then add an argument ot the function `function disableDrag(item)` and within that function change `$(this).draggable({disabled: true})` to `$(item).draggable("option", "disabled", true);`.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p564qdhf/)**

Comment: There is still an error in the console with this one.